# Solve partial equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$x z_x + y z_y =x+y+z$
Solve for z if $z(x,x+1)=2x+1$.

I have used characteristic method to get $y=cx$. How to find the second solution to get the general solution?

Comment: Can you show your work to get $y=cx$ as you said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x z_x + y z_y =x+y+z$$
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{x+y+z}$$
Solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}$ :
$$\frac{y}{x}=c_1$$
Solving $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dz}{x+c_1x+z}$ :
$$\frac{z}{x}-(c_1+1)\ln|x|=c_2$$
$c_2=F(c_1)\quad$ with arbitrary function $F$.

General solution of the PDE :
$$\boxed{z(x,y)=\left(\frac{y}{x}+1\right)x\ln|x|+xF\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}$$
Condition $z(x,x+1)=2x+1$.
$$z(x,x+1)=2x+1=(2x+1)\ln|x|+xF\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)$$
$X=\frac{x+1}{x}\quad\implies\quad x=\frac{1}{X-1}$
$$2\frac{1}{X-1}+1=(2\frac{1}{X-1}+1)\ln|\frac{1}{X-1}|+\frac{1}{X-1}F\left(X\right)$$
$$F(X)=X+1+(X+1)\ln|X-1|$$
Putting $F(X=y/x)$ into the above general solution :
$$\boxed{z(x,y)=x+y+(x+y)\ln|x-y|}$$